# When is $\limsup_{n \to \infty} (a_n+b_n) = \limsup_{n \to \infty} a_n +\limsup_{n \to \infty} b_n$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limsup-and-liminf

I know that $$\limsup\limits_{n \to \infty} (a_n+b_n) \le \limsup\limits_{n \to \infty} a_n +\limsup\limits_{n \to \infty} b_n.$$ But what should apply to A and B if we should have "=" ?

I can't find anything about it in my notes.

Comment: To see the kind of problem that can arise, consider $a_n=(-1)^n$ and $b_n=(-1)^{n+1}$.

Comment: Equality largely depends on how subsequences which converge to $\limsup_{n\to\infty}a_n$, $\liminf_{n\to\infty}a_n$, $\limsup_{n\to\infty}b_n$ or $\liminf_{n\to\infty}b_n$ intertwine, and there isn't an easy way (if at all) to describe this, unless of course the situation trivialises somehow (say, $\limsup_{n\to\infty} (a_n+b_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n+\limsup_{n\to\infty} b_n$ when $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n$ exists).

Comment: Thank you. 
The same goes for liminf? Also $$\liminf\limits_{n \to \infty} (a_n+b_n) = \limlimits_{n \to \infty} a_n +\liminf\limits_{n \to \infty} b_n.$$ if a_n er convergent?

Answer (score 0):

As a previous commenter stated, it is sufficient that if either $\lim a_n$ or $\lim b_n$ exists, then equality holds. However, note that if $a_n=\sin(\tan(n))$ and $b_n=\tan(\sin(n))$, then $$\limsup(a_n+b_n)=\limsup(a_n)+\limsup(b_n)=1+\tan(1)$$

And neither limit as $n\to\infty$ exists. So the convergence of one of the sequences isn't a necessary condition to characterize this equality.